# XSLT - eliminate descendent node using except

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Assume I have a sample XML file like this,

```
<Entry>
    <lang>
        <definition>definition</definition>
        <note>aaaaaaaaa
            <list>
                <list-item>aabbbbbbbb</list-item>
                <list-item>aacccccccc</list-item>
                <list-item>aadddddddd</list-item>
            </list>
        </note>
        <example>bbbbbbbbbbb
            <list>
                <list-item>bbaaaaaaa</list-item>
                <list-item>bbbbbbbbbbb</list-item>
                <list-item>bbcccccccc</list-item>
            </list>
        </example>
    </lang>
</Entry>
```

and I've written sample xsl like this,

```
<xsl:template match="Entry">
        <term>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except definition"/>
        </term>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="definition">
        <para type="definition">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="lang">
        <para type="Lang">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="example">
        <para type="example">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list">
        <para type="list">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="list-item">
        <para type="list-item">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </para>
    </xsl:template>
```

As I've written in the template for `Entry` I need to eliminate the `<definition>` content from the output. (`<xsl:apply-templates select="node() except definition"/>`).

As I know I can suppress the element like  `<xsl:template match="definition"/>` and eliminate the content but in my real scenario I cannot use that method. and it seems `except` keyword only works for child element of given node but not descendant element as above example.

Any suggestions how can I eliminate that `<definition>` within apply-template in `xsl:template match="Entry"` ? (not using supress `definition` element or using different mode)

Comment: Why can't you use an empty template in your real-world scenario?  Provide some sample XML that demonstrates why that won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `definition` is a child of `lang` - so if you want to eliminate it, you need to do it when calling templates from `lang`:

```
<xsl:template match="lang">
    <para type="Lang">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except definition"/>
    </para>
</xsl:template>
```

What you have now applies templates to all nodes that are children of `Entry`, except `definition`. But since `definition` is not a child of `Entry` to begin with, the exception is meaningless.

> and it seems `except` keyword only works for child element of given node
>   but not descendant element as above example.

No, `except` works for any set of nodes that precedes it.

---

### Added:

> But even if I write `xsl:apply-templates select="node() except
>   descendant::definition"` ...  `<definition>` content does not
>   eliminate?

When you write:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node()">
```

that's an abbreviation of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()">
```

Adding `except descendant::definition` to that is meaningless. It is the equivalent of:

```
A, B, C except D
```

You would see a different result if you wrote:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::node() except descendant::definition"/>
```

but that would also change the structure of your output. If you want to preserve the original hierarchy, you must apply templates recursively from parent to child - as you have done.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But even if I write xsl:apply-templates select="node() except descendant::definition" instead of xsl:apply-templates select="node() except definition" within template match="Entry", <definition> content does not eliminate?

Comment: @sanjay See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @sanjay Is this question not answered?

Answer (score 0):

You've clearly got a deep misunderstanding of the processing model, judging by your comments on the (perfectly good) answers you have been given.

Firstly, xsl:apply-templates selects a set of nodes, and processes each of those nodes using the best-match template rule for each one.

So `<apply-templates select="node()"/>` applies templates to all the nodes selected by the expression `node()`, that is, all children of the context node.

Now, what nodes does the expression "node() except definition" select? Answer: all the child nodes except those that are named "definition". Since there are no child nodes named "definition", it selects exactly the same nodes as the expression "node()".

What you are attempting to do is some kind of "action at a distance": you're trying to say "process these nodes in the normal way, but while you're doing so, if at any time you reach a node called "definition", then ignore it". XSLT doesn't work that way, and nor does any other programming language: you can't alter the effect of some function or template that's indirectly invoked except by passing parameters that it understands. The nearest you can get is by passing tunnel parameters, but they would only modify the effect of a template that's explicitly written to look for those parameters.

But that's an over-complicated way of achieving what you want. There are two ways to ensure that definition elements are not processed:

(a) don't select them for processing. The place you select them for processing is from the template with match="lang", so that's what you need to change.

(b) ensure that if they are selected for processing, the processing produces no output, which means changing the template rule for the `definition` element.